# Newest blender 2.8: Object visible in render button missing

Tags: rendering, objects, visibility

In the latest version of blender 2.8 I can not find the button for an object that allows it to be shown in the rendered image. There is only one 'eye' icon left, which makes the object invisible/visible in the viewport.

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Render Icon it's hidden by default

You have to enable it from the *Filter* sub-menu.

Look for the camera icon in the *Restriction Toggles* section.

[image]

It has been hidden by default in order to tide up things a bit.

As you can see, now there are many possible controls you can enable/disable for the outliner, so they decided it was better to give the user the choice to costumize the right column.

You can see Pablo discussing this aspect in one of the Blender today videos:

https://youtu.be/GUa1jC01d_E?t=2093

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: @gábor don't post thank you comments. If an answer helped you upvote it, and if it completely solved your problem consider marking it as accepted

Comment: They should make this show up by default