# How to render full model in Blender?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I have a 3D model made out of different shapes. Most of them appear on the render. Except for one ring. I tried pressing ctrl-H, and setting render mode to "Cycles" but it didn't work. I'm working with a Mac and Blender 2.9, by the way.

[image: Here is the 3D object]

The 3D object in Blender

[image]

The render of the 3D model

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Have you disabled rendering the missing? Enable the toggle for the outliner. It's the camera icon, have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/141914/107598

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the advise. I disabled all the restrictions for the shape, but it doesn't appear in render mode.